# Error in the code due to type mismatch

Tags: haskell

In this code there is an error sue to mismatch.

```
   import System.IO
   loop :: Int -> [Int] -> IO ()
   loop 0 ls = return ls
   loop n ls = do  newNumber <- readLn
            loop (n-1) (newNumber:ls)


   main = do 
   putStrLn "Please enter the number"
   number <- readLn :: IO Int
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show number
   xs <- loop number []
   print xs
```

The error message is:

```
treep.hs:4:20:
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[Int]'
In the first argument of `return', namely `ls'
In the expression: return ls
In an equation for `loop': loop 0 ls = return ls
```

how can i remove the error

Comment: @tikhon please see this piece of code

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `loop` function? Its signature says that it takes an integer (`Int`) a list of integers (`[Int]`) and return an action.

Comment: I want the loop to run n number of times and return the list of n numbers in the end

Comment: I think you made a typo copying Tikhon's answer from your other question: try changing `IO ()` in the signature of `loop` to `IO [Int]` like the type error suggests; `loop` is trying to return a list of integers, after all!

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, your `loop` function should return `IO [Int]`, like so:

```
loop :: Int -> IO [Int]
```

Then the first case is:

```
loop 0 = return []
```

The second one should be similar to what you wrote (without passing in `ls` which is your result, not an input).

BTW, the error can be explained this way:

```
loop :: Int -> [Int] -> IO ()     -- line 1
loop 0 ls = return ls             -- line 2
```

In line 1, you tell the compiler that the `loop` function takes two arguments, an `Int` and a `[Int]`. In line 2, you use `0` (which is an Int, thus it's fine), and `ls`. So, `ls` is of type `[Int]`. The signature for `return` is `return :: a -> m a`, the return type depends on the Monad `m` (in your case `IO`) and on the input type which is `[Int]`. Therefore, the type of `return ls` is `IO [Int]`, but you told the compiler on line 1 that you it should be `IO ()'. (Exactly what the compiler told you by the error message. ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

`ls` has type `[Int]`, so `return ls` has type `IO [Int]`. However, your type signature says that the function should return `IO ()`. It looks like you simply got the type signature wrong. This should work:

```
loop :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
```